MAUI app flickers white between page changes in dark theme
In our MAUI app, in order to support dark mode we set all ContentPage elements in xaml to have:
BackgroundColor="{AppThemeBinding Light=White, Dark=Black}"

This works but when changing pages the screen briefly shows white when the page first loads before changing to black. The white lasts about half a second but is obviously very disorienting for someone using dark mode.
It is worth mentioning that we are not using the following common method to change pages as it didn't offer the flexibility we desired:
Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(MyApp.View.MyPage)); 

But instead, throughout the app we are using the following method to change pages, which may affect the issue:
Application.Current.MainPage = new MyPage();

What we've tried to fix the flickering
In App.xaml (this did not solve the issue):
<Style TargetType="ContentPage">
    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light=White, Dark=Black}" />
</Style>

In MauiProgram.cs (this did also not solve the issue):
Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.PageHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping(nameof(Page), (handler, view) =>
{
    handler.PlatformView.SetBackgroundColor(
        App.CurrentTheme == AppTheme.Dark ?
        AndroidGraphics.Color.Black : AndroidGraphics.Color.White);
});

Another try in MauiProgram.cs did not solve the issue:
Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.WindowHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping(nameof(IWindow), (handler, view) =>
{
    var activity = Platform.CurrentActivity;
    activity?.Window?.DecorView?.SetBackgroundColor(App.CurrentTheme == AppTheme.Dark ?
        AndroidGraphics.Color.Black : AndroidGraphics.Color.White);
});


To fix this we had to call this method when starting up the app in OnStart() in App.Xaml.cs and also call this if the user manually changes the theme in the in-app settings
public static void SetActivityColor()
{
#if ANDROID
    var activity = Platform.CurrentActivity;
    activity?.Window?.DecorView?.SetBackgroundColor(
        App.CurrentTheme == AppTheme.Dark ?
        Android.Graphics.Color.Black :
        Android.Graphics.Color.White);
#endif
}

Unsure if this will be needed for IOS

Actually, you can put the code into the MainActivity's OnCreate method directly.
